# Solving 403 permission denied error on Apache even after Allow From All and Chmod 777?

Tags: php, macos, apache, permissions, http-status-code-403

My DocumentRoot is in ~/Dropbox/Websites. It's set up as Allow From All and AllowOverride All in the vhosts and in httpd.conf, and I've even put 777 permissions on the entire DocumentRoot recursively (it's just a local dev env., I'd never do it live, don't worry). This works like a charm on Ubuntu and Windows, but on OSX it keeps telling me Permission Denied. What else can I try? Is there a way to see WHY a permission was denied? It would be nice if I at least got a hint like "_www is not allowed access to this folder" or ".htaccess does not allow entry into this folder", but this generic message is of zero help.

I have also tried changing the owner of the directory to _www:_www which is what Apache runs as on OSX, to no avail, nothing has changed.

Error log entry:

```
[Fri Feb 01 12:31:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

Access log entry:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013:12:31:42 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013:12:31:42 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"
```

More info:
The virtual hosts work. The access errors get logged in their proper location, under /logs inside the vhost folder itself, I just can't get past the 403 error. I assume this means it's a .htaccess problem of some kind, since apache obviously succeeds in writing to the folder, no?

Comment: Have you checked your Apache logs?

Comment: It's no big deal, local dev environment. Updating main question now.

Comment: @Yuliy, not sure how to do that

Comment: @Swader http://sysadmin.circularvale.com/debugging/using-strace-to-analyze-apache/

Comment: I'm afraid there's no strace on OS X and I have no idea how to use DTruss, which seems to be the alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC, on OS X your home directory is not executable by world by default, so it can't get to any directory under that either.  You can check with `ls -ld ~`, and fix it with `chmod go+x ~`.  Make sure that every directory above your document root is at least world executable.

Comment: Interesting theory, thanks. No effect after applying "chmod go+x ~" though

Comment: Actually, adding the -R flag did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
onlineoffline

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
```

Just do this in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf/httpd.conf and restart the apache.